# JPA multiple joins

Tags: jpa, join, jpql

I have these classes

```
class Project {
    @ManyToOne Company owner;
    @ManyToMany Set<Person> resources;
}
class Company {
    @ManyToOne Country country;
}
class Person {
}
```

How can I write a JPQL to get the all the resources working on projects for companies in a specific country?

The one below doesn't seem to work (using DataNucleus)

```
SELECT r FROM Project p JOIN p.resources r JOIN p.owner c WHERE c.country = :country
```

It tries to join `r` with `c` and of course does not have the `owner` property and a NullPointerException is raised inside DataNucleus.

Comment: I also tried

    SELECT r FROM Project p INNER JOIN p.resources r WHERE EXISTS (SELECT c FROM Company c WHERE c.country = :country AND p.owner = c)

but it complains that 'owner' is not a property in Person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you expect:

```
SELECT resource FROM Project p INNER JOIN p.resources as resource
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot a part of the initial question:

```
SELECT resource FROM Project p INNER JOIN p.resources as resource where p.owner.country = :country
```

Comment: And as far as I know, a JOIN is INNER by default, so INNER can be omitted. Same goes for as. Then practically the solution is only the first part of what I gave and said it's not working.

Comment: Have you tried a simple where clause on `owner.country` ?  
  
`SELECT resource FROM Project p INNER JOIN p.resources as resource where p.owner.country = :country`